# How to implement toastify Here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement toastify inside my `toBeCalledByEventListener()` function .

actually I don't know where I implement those in my function:

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

and

```
const notify = () => toast("Wow so easy!");
```

and

```
<button onClick={notify}>Notify!</button>
```

any suggestion please.

my function look like this:I want to implement toastify here

```
async function toBeCalledByEventListener() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/generate_pdf', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const pdfURL = responseData.pdf_url;
        localStorage.setItem("pdf_url", pdfURL)
        // window.open(pdfURL, '_blank');
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    } 
};

return (
 <Button
            variant="large"
            className={styles.lightgreenButton}
            onClick={toBeCalledByEventListener}
          >
            {t('print')}
  </Button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the toast function wherever you need it.

```js
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const notify = () => toast("Wow so easy!");

async function toBeCalledByEventListener() {
   ...
     // if the response was successful call the notification function
     const responseData = await response.json();
     const pdfURL = responseData.pdf_url;
     localStorage.setItem("pdf_url", pdfURL)
     // window.open(pdfURL, '_blank');
     notify()
     if (!response.ok) {
       toast("An unexpected error occurred, please try again later.")
       throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
     }


   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to toast where you console. try the code below:

```
async function toBeCalledByEventListener() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/generate_pdf', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const pdfURL = responseData.pdf_url;
        localStorage.setItem("pdf_url", pdfURL)
        // window.open(pdfURL, '_blank');
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        toast(error) // where i add some code
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    } 
}
```

Because the function named notify cannot pass any params, just use the function toast instead.

Answer (score 0):

**it is the function changes**

```
async function toBeCalledByEventListener() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/generate_pdf', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
    
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const pdfURL = responseData.pdf_url;
        localStorage.setItem("pdf_url", pdfURL);
    
        // Display a success toast
        toast.success("PDF generated successfully!");
    
        // window.open(pdfURL, '_blank');
    
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Display an error toast
        toast.error('Error generating PDF:', error.message);
      }
    }
```

**your app.js changes :**

```
function App() {
  // ... other components

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... other content */}
      <ToastContainer /> {/* Add this line */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have modified your code and make it easy to use.

Make sure you have react-toastify installed. You can install it using npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify

Import the necessary components and styles from react-toastify at the top of your file.

```
// Import required dependency 
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const ErrorHandling = () => {
    
    // Create a function that will be responsible for showing the error notification. In your case, it's the notify function.
    const notify = (msg) => toast.error(msg);

    async function toBeCalledByEventListener() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('/generate_pdf', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          });
      
          const responseData = await response.json();
          const pdfURL = responseData.pdf_url;
          localStorage.setItem('pdf_url', pdfURL);
      
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
          }
      
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);

        //   Update your error handling logic to use the notify function whenever an error occurs.
        notify('Network response was not ok');
        }
      }
      

      useEffect(()=>{
        toBeCalledByEventListener();
      },[])

  return (
    // Finally, render the ToastContainer component at the root level of your component.
    <>
     <ToastContainer  />
    </>
  )
}

export default ErrorHandling
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: hey.tnx again.
where should i return my <ToastContainer  />  .
is it here?

<Button
            variant="large"
            className={styles.lightgreenButton}
            onClick={toBeCalledByEventListener}
          >
            {t('print')}
          </Button>

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the toast function where you need to try the below code. It works for me and codeSandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/toastify-x6xyrd)

```
async function toBeCalledByEventListener() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/generate_pdf", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    const responseData = await response.json();
    const pdfURL = responseData.pdf_url;

    localStorage.setItem("pdf_url", pdfURL);

    toast.success("PDF generated successfully!", {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: 3000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);

    toast.error("Error generating PDF. Please try again later.", {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: 3000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
    });
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toBeCalledByEventListener}>Generate PDF</button>
      <ToastContainer />
    </>
  );
}
```